# converting unstacked dataframe into a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

This dataframe is a result of unstacking another dataframe.

```
cost                 10        20        30
-------------------------------------------
cycles
--------------------------------------------
1                     2         4         6
2                     1         2         3
3                     3         6         9
4                     1         0         5
```

I want something like this:

```
cycles                10        20        30
-----------------------------------------------
1                     2         4         6
2                     1         2         3
3                     3         6         9
4                     1         0         5
```

I am a little confused about pivoting in the unstacked dataframes. I went through a couple of other similar posts but I really couldn't understand. I want to perform regression on every column of this dataframe. I figured it would be difficult to access the cycles column in the first dataframe, so I would really appreciate if someone can shed any light on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
df.reset_index()
```

Edit: To drop the axis name `cost`, you need to use:

```
df.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
```

This will still return an index, that is just the way pandas works, but it will not have a label floating over it.  If you want `cycle` as the index without `cost`, you can just use the first part:

```
df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Comment: :   This works definitely. But the index column would be 'cost' in this case. Is there anyway I can get rid of it?